# Runtime Error :member access within misaligned address in C programming in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [23. Merge k Sorted Lists](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/):

> You are given an array of `k` linked-lists `lists`, each linked-list is sorted in ascending order.
>
> *Merge all the linked-lists into one sorted linked-list and return it.*
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - `k == lists.length`
> - `0 <= k <= 104`
> - `0 <= lists[i].length <= 500`
> - `-104 <= lists[i][j] <= 104`
> - `lists[i]` is sorted in ascending order.
> - The sum of `lists[i].length` will not exceed 10<sup>4</sup>.

When submitting my code, I get this error:

```
Line 70: Char 15: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0x7fc00000000c for type 'struct ListNode', which requires 8 byte alignment [ListNode.c]
0x7fc00000000c: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>
```

Why isn't it working? I tried to merge *k* lists using the first algorithm of merging two lists, which is tested and correct! Any explanation please to my problem?

This is the code I submitted to LeetCode:

```c
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */

struct ListNode* mergeTwoLists(struct ListNode* list1, struct ListNode* list2)
{
    if (list1==NULL && list2==NULL)
        return NULL;
    struct ListNode head  ;
    struct ListNode *result = &head;
    while (list1 && list2) {
       if (list1->val < list2->val) {
           result->next=list1;
           list1=list1->next;
           result = result->next;
       }
       else {
           result->next=list2;
           list2=list2->next;
           result = result->next;
       }
    }
    if (list1) {
        result->next=list1;//????????????????????????????????????
    }
    if (list2) {
        result->next=list2;
    }
    return head.next;
}

struct ListNode* mergeKLists(struct ListNode** lists, int listsSize)
{
   struct ListNode head;
   struct ListNode *result = &head;
   result=mergeTwoLists(lists[0],lists[1]);
   for (int i = 2; i<listsSize; i++) {
       result=mergeTwoLists(result,lists[i]);
   }
   return head.next;
}
```

I would like to know the reason of this error.

Comment: Please don't dump such an unreadable bunch of test. Apply proper indentation. Also don't write multiple instructions in one line. Only do this if you hate people who read your code.

Comment: In `mergeKLists` you don't seem to be initializing `head`'s fields.

Comment: In particular, none of the code in `mergeKLists` does anything at all with the object `head`, except the last line that returns whatever garbage was in its `next` member.  You begin by pointing `result` to `head`, but then you never do anything with `result` before overwriting it in the next line.  `result = ...` only changes the *pointer* and does nothing at all to the object it *points to*.

Comment: Questions asking about bugs in code generally need to provide a [mcve].  This isn't reproducible because it doesn't have headers, `main` function, etc, so a person can't compile and test it without a bunch of extra work and guessing as to how to fill those parts in.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your `mergeKLists` function:

- The code assumes that there are at least 2 lists given, but there might be just one list, or even none. Note the range of `k` in the code challenge description. In case `k` is 0 or 1, you'll provide undefined reference(s) to `mergeTwoLists`, leading to the errors you encounter
- `return head.next` returns an uninitialised value, as `head` was only declared and then ignored.
- The assignment `*result = &head` is useless, as `result` is overwritten with a new value in the next statement.

Here is a correction:

```
struct ListNode* mergeKLists(struct ListNode** lists, int listsSize)
{
    if (listsSize == 0) return NULL; // Boundary case: no lists
    struct ListNode *result = lists[0]; // We are sure there is this first list
    for (int i = 1; i<listsSize; i++) {
        result=mergeTwoLists(result,lists[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```